# Update trigger does not update for all rows in a set based update query

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, set-based

I have the tables Cities and Countries with the following triggers:

[image]

When I update any City, it should insert a row into the Audit table saying 'The City with ID 'any ID' has been modified'. Cities table has a foreign key relationship with Countries table (Cities.CountryID = Countries.ID).

What I expect trCountryUpdate to do is, when I update a Country row, it should insert row into the Audit table for all the Cities having the updated Country ID.

However, when I update the name of Country with ID 1, it should have inserted 5 rows into the Audit table as there are 5 corresponding Cities for CountryID 1. However, it always inserts 1 row.

Please let me know what should be done to insert 5 rows into Audit table for 5 cities having CountryID 1 when Country with ID 1 is updated.

PS:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[trCityUpdate]
on [dbo].[Cities]
for update
as

declare @cityIdModified int;
select @cityIdModified = ID from inserted;
Insert into Audit values ('The City with ID ' + cast(@cityIdModified as varchar(1)) + ' has been modified')

go

ALTER trigger [dbo].[trCountryUpdate]
on [dbo].[Countries]
for update
as

declare @countryIdModified int;
select @countryIdModified = ID from inserted;

update ci
set ci.CountryID = @countryIdModified
from Cities ci 
join Countries co on co.ID = ci.CountryID
where ci.CountryID = @countryIdModified
```

Comment: The 'Select @CityModified = ID from Inserted' returns only 1 value not the 5 of them.

Comment: Shouldn't trCountryUpdate trigger trCityUpdate 5 times?

Comment: No they are being updated at once.

Comment: Ok. Are there any other ways updating Country could insert 5 rows for each city in Audit table? without using cursor..

Comment: Please post code as (formatted) text, not as pictures. We can't copy/paste text in a picture, and pictures are not searchable.

Comment: I have update the question with text

Comment: `inserted` contains *all* of the rows. Your assignments to scalar variables effectively take one row's values and ignore the rest. It's mean to be used like a *table*, and clearly you're already aware of joins.

Comment: You have to use inserted table. As Inserted table having all updated records.

Modify trCityUpdate trigger as like below.

Insert into Audit 
SELECT ('The City with ID ' + cast(ID as varchar(20)) + ' has been modified')
from inserted

Comment: Ah. Yes. It is done now.

ALTER trigger [dbo].[trCityUpdate]
on [dbo].[Cities]
for update
as

Insert into Audit(Text)
select 'The City with ID ' + cast(ID as varchar(1)) + ' has been modified' 
from inserted;

Great. Thank you

Comment: Please add this as an answer. Let me accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your replies. It was a great help :)

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[trCityUpdate]
on [dbo].[Cities]
for update
as

Insert into Audit(Text)
select 'The City with ID ' + cast(ID as varchar(1)) + ' has been modified' 
from inserted
```

When 5 rows in Cities table are updated, trCityUpdate is called only once, **not 5 times**. The inserted table contains 5 updated rows.